Is there a space that has points $G_\delta$ that is not countably tight?
Is there a space that has points $G_\delta$ (a.k.a. has countable pseudocharacter) that is not countably tight? $\pi$-Base knows of no such examples as of today.
Naively, one might try this: given a $G_\delta$ limit point $x$ of $A$ witnessed by $U_n$, pick a point $x_n\in U_n\cap A$. It's not clear to me that $x$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}_n$ though.

The countable complement extension topology on the real numbers is such an example. This space is the smallest topology generated by the union of the topologies from S25: Euclidean Real Numbers and S17: Cocountable topology on $\mathbb R$.
It has points $G_\delta$ because each singleton $\{x\}$ is the intersection of open sets $(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})$.
It is not countably tight because it is not discrete, yet countable sets are discrete. More particularly, $(0,1)$ has $0$ is a limit point: every neighborhood of $0$ is of the form $(-x,x)\setminus C$ for some countable $C$ and thus must intersect $(0,1)$. But there exists no countable set $D\subseteq(0,1)$ that contains $0$ in its closure, since countable sets are closed in this space.

Here is a counter-example:
Let $R$ be a domain (i.e., a commutative ring with $0 \neq 1$
and $0$ is the only zero-divisor), not a field.
It is easy to see that the set of all non-singleton cosets is a base for a non-discrete topology on $R$, which is a ring topology with the set of all non-zero ideals as a neighborhood base of $0$. Since each non-singleton coset is clopen, it is, in fact, zero-dimensional $T_2$, thus completely regular.
(I think this topology is called ideal topology, on the integers it is also called "Fürstenberg topology".)
Now let $R$ be a unique factorization domain with uncountably many pairwise non-associated primes (for instance $\mathbb R[X]$, the ring of polynomials over the reals).
Points are $G_\delta.$

[For an arbitrary prime $p$ of $R$, it is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} p^nR = \{0\}$.
Hence $0$ is $G_\delta$.
Since $R$ is a topological group, hence homogeneous, every point is $G_\delta$.]
Countable subsets are closed, discrete.

[Again, by homogenity, we may consider a countable set
$A \subset R$, such that $ 0 \notin  A$.
Then there is a prime $p$, which does not divide any element of $A$.
Hence $pR \cap A = \emptyset$.
Hence $0 \notin \overline{A}$.

This also implies that countable subsets are discrete.
(Although, formally, this is not needed for the next implication.)
]
Since $R$ is not discrete, this implies that $R$ is not countably tight.

Thanks Ulli. I'm sure this is correct, but I'll have to derust on my algebra to follow some of the details.

My instinct is that there might be a more elementary characterization on the $\sigma$-product of countably-many reals (subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega$ with cofinite coordinates zero).

@Steven in your last comment, did you mean $\mathbb R^{\omega_1}$?

I did not: I'm considering the bijection of $\mathbb R[x]$ onto $\sigma\mathbb R^\omega$ mapping the coefficient of x^n to the nth coordinate. If I understood the broad strokes of your answer, at least.

Ah, understood. But I think the ideal topology is much finer than the $\sigma$-product topology. If I see this correctly, this should be the ring topology, which has ${x^n \mathbb R[x]: n \in \mathbb N}$ as a neighborhood base of $0$. Of course, here
$\mathbb R$ has the discrete topology. Also note that this one is metrizable.

Perhaps it's worth to mention, that even with respect to this coarser topology $\mathbb R[x]$ is a countable union of closed, discrete subspaces, hence each subset is $G_\delta$. Of course, this is also true for the finer ideal topology.
